# What is the TaskScheduler in azure functions?

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-functions, taskscheduler

I could not find any applicable documentation about this. What is the default `TaskScheduler` when using Azure Functions?

Ideally, I would like it to be based off of threadpool - i.e., [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_Default) - but I do not have any certainty in that respect and it affects whether I should stick `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere or not.

P.S.: There is one code path where impersonation is involved.

Comment: If it's not documented then it's very likely the default. You can easily verify this by checking if `TaskScheduler.Current` is an instance of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`